# Reading Table Data using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I've tried searching for this one, and tried multiple solutions that I found on here. But so far nothing is working.

The table I'm trying to get data from is being created after entering something into the page. The site then pulls data from what I entered and creates a table. I've had issues with just getting the driver to wait for the table to be visible, it can't find the element.

Here's some html.

```
<table id="products">
 <thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr class="template subheading-template subheading draggable removeable">
   <tr class="template spec-template draggable product removeable odd">
   <tr class="components hide modify">
   <tr class="draggable product removeable even" data-id="G38180">
    <td class="drag"/>
    <td>
    <td class="cell-gpn">G38180</td>
    <td class="cell-rpn">0729151158PROD2</td>
    <td class="cell-1 editable">
    <td class="cell-2 editable">
    <td class="cell-3 editable">
    <td class="cell-4 editable">
```

The cells I want data from have the class "cell-gpn" and "cell-rpn".

Here's some of the code I've tried.

```
public String getTableData(WebElement table,String rowNumber, String cellNumber){
    String text = "";
    WebElement row = table.findElement(By.xpath("./tr[" + rowNumber + "]"));
    WebElement key = row.findElement(By.xpath("./td[" + cellNumber + "]"));
    text = key.getText();

    return text;

}
```

Where table is

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//table[@id='products']")
public WebElement relatedProductsTableRows;
```